# Coloring a sub-table

Tags: tables

I want modify the following example  to obtain a colored sub-table (only the border) as in the present picture.

[image: sub-table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 3 & 2& B&  C \\
\hline
A & B&  C& B&  C \\
\hline
D & E & K& B&  F \\
\hline
G & H & I& B&  C\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Not that elegant, but you could use a combination of `\cline` and `\multicolumn` to achieve the desired red frame around the four cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 3 & 2& B&  C \\
\cline{1-2} \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{3-4} \arrayrulecolor{black}\cline{5-5}
A & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{red}\vrule}}{B}& C& \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{red}\vrule}}{B}&  C \\
\hline
D & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{red}\vrule}}{E} & K& \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{red}\vrule}}{B}&  F \\
\cline{1-2} \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{3-4} \arrayrulecolor{black}\cline{5-5}
G & H & I& B&  C\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

That's just for fun: you can draw pretty much anything with tikz, so why not here? In particular, when using `tikzmark` you can conveniently annotate whatever you already have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & \tikzmarknode{3}{3} & 2& B&  C \\
\hline
A & B&  \tikzmarknode{C1}{C}& B&  C \\
\hline
D & E & K& \tikzmarknode{B}{B}&  F \\
\hline
G & H & I& B&  \tikzmarknode{C2}{C}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,thick] ([yshift=-1pt]$(3)!0.5!(C1)$) rectangle ([yshift=-1pt]$(B)!0.5!(C2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be clear, I am not suggesting to use this if you only want to draw some red lines. In this case, I think that [Leandris' very nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462759/121799) is the way to go. However, at the very moment you are interested in more fancy things, then this here might be the way to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & \tikzmarknode{3}{3} & 2& B&  C \\
\hline
A & B&  \tikzmarknode{C1}{C}& B&  C \\
\hline
D & E & K& \tikzmarknode{B}{B}&  F \\
\hline
G & H & I& B&  \tikzmarknode{C2}{C}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\newlength{\Border}
\Border=0.8pt
\fill[left color=red,right color=blue,shading angle=45,even odd rule] 
([yshift={-1pt+0.5\Border},xshift={-0.5\Border}]$(3)!0.5!(C1)$) rectangle 
([yshift={-1-0.5\Border},xshift={+0.5\Border}]$(B)!0.5!(C2)$)
[rounded corners]
([yshift={-1pt-0.5\Border},xshift={0.5\Border}]$(3)!0.5!(C1)$) rectangle 
([yshift={-1pt+0.5\Border},xshift={-0.5\Border}]$(B)!0.5!(C2)$)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\cellcolor{..}` to color single cells. You need the `xcolor` package or just the `colortbl` package, the former loads the latter. Note that some PDF viewers hide table lines behind the color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 3 & 2& B&  C \\\hline
A & B&  \cellcolor{blue!25}C& \cellcolor{blue!25}B&  C \\\hline
D & E & \cellcolor{blue!25}K& \cellcolor{blue!25}B&  F \\\hline
G & H & I& B&  C \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want please  coloring only  the border.

Comment: @user105476, than you need to make your question more clear. please edit it and explain what you like to have. above answer gives exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is based upon `{array}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows, and columns.

Thus, it's possible to draw whatever rule you want by using Tikz.

Remark: In fact, `{NiceTabular}` has a key `hvlines` which draws (in black) all the horizontal and vertical rules in the tabular. I have used that key (and drawn the rectangle in red with Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
1 & 3 & 2& B&  C \\
A & B&  C& B&  C \\
D & E & K& B&  F \\
G & H & I& B&  C \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw [red, thick] (2-|3) rectangle (4-|5) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

It's also possible to use the command `\Block` (provided by `nicematrix`) in the array itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
1 & 3 & 2& B&  C \\
A & B & \Block[draw=red,line-width=1pt,transparent]{2-2}{}
        C& B&  C \\
D & E & K& B&  F \\
G & H & I& B&  C \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.