# Get single cell borders to have their own colors

Tags: tables, cellspace

I have following table in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r *{10}{| c}}
    \cline{2-9}
    1 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black}  \\ \cline{2-9}
    2 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black} \\ \cline{2-9}
    3 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    4 & & & & & & & & \\ \cline{2-9}
    5 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    6 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    7 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    8 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{e} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{g} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{h}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How would I go about getting single borders (not rows or columns, but for example the left side of a specific cell) to have a specific color? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related: [Coloring a sub-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462753/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinkering around with `hhline`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r *{10}{| c}}
    \cline{2-9}
    1 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black}  \\ \cline{2-9}
    2 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black} \\ \cline{2-9}
    3 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    4 & & & & & & & & \\ \cline{2-9}
    5 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    6 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \hhline{~|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{red}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-|-|-|-|}
    7 & & & \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red}\vline}c!{\color{red}\vline}}{}  & & & & &  \\ 
        \hhline{~|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{red}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|-|-|-|-|-|}
    8 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{e} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{g} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{h}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Also works at the right edge

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r *{10}{| c}}
    \cline{2-9}
    1 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black}  \\ \cline{2-9}
    2 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black} \\ \cline{2-9}
    3 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    4 & & & & & & & & \\ \cline{2-9}
    5 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    6 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{red}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}
    7 & & &  & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red}\vline}c!{\color{red}\vline}}{}   \\ 
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{red}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}
    8 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{e} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{g} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{h}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

and with cell colours

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{r *{10}{| c}}
    \cline{2-9}
    1 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black}  \\ \cline{2-9}
    2 & & & & & & & & \cellcolor{black} \\ \cline{2-9}
    3 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    4 & & & & & & & & \\ \cline{2-9}
    5 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    6 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{red}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}
    7 & & &  & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red}\vline}c!{\color{red}\vline}}{\cellcolor{yellow}}   \\ 
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|>{\arrayrulecolor{red}}-|>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-|}
    8 & & & & & & & &  \\ \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{b} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{c} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{d} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{e} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{f} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{g} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{h}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use the \multicolumn idea of yours for a cell on the rightmost column, it doesn't work, since it pushes the existing color into the next row. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @MateInTwo Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem with the rightmost column? I just tested (see the edit to my answer) and while the alignment is not perfect when zoomed in, I don't see any colour in the next row.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen the actual problem - it doesn't work if the cell is already colored. I put the two vertical red bars into the field h2 and that's where it bugged. It works fine if the cell is uncolored and on the right.

Comment: @MateInTwo Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I copied the code from your example and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (as provided by the package `array`) but creates PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns.

Then it's possible to use those nodes with TikZ in the co-called `\CodeAfter` to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{*{8}{c}}[first-col,last-row,hvlines]
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    4 \\
    5 \\
    6 \\
    7 \\
    8 \\
      & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h
  \CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [red] (6-|3) -- (7-|3) ; 
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

It's also possible to use the command `\Block` (provided by `niceamtrix`) and its key `borders` to draw the border of the cell with the command inserted at the right place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{*{8}{c}}[first-col,last-row,hvlines]
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    4 \\
    5 \\
    6 & & \Block[borders={tikz={color=red},right}]{}{}\\
    7 \\
    8 \\
      & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]