# Color the lines of only a single cell of a tabular

Tags: tables, color

I have the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{black}\vrule}c!{\color{gray}\vrule}c!{\color{gray}\vrule}c!{\color{black}\vrule}}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\hline
    & & \\
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline
    & this one & \\
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline
    & & \\
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Now I want to color just the lines surrounding this cell.

How can I achieve this?

Everything I was able to find related to coloring an entire horizontal or vertical line of a table.

Comment: You could use a combination of `\cline` and `\vrule` as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462759/134144  or `tikz` as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462767/134144

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Just had to use `\hhline` instead of `\cline`

Comment: So this question can be closed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: Yes, this question can be closed.