# Bold part of column in table

Tags: tables

i want to do table, where i indicate the best results of tests. To do it i have to bold properly rows and columns. With

```
\Xcline{2-5}{2pt}
```

i can bold rows, but how can i do the same thing with columns?[image]

Code which i use to draw table:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{board}{tag} & tag1 & tag2 & tag3 &  tag4 \\ \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{board1} & qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{board2} & qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} \hline\Xcline{2-5}{1.5pt}
  \multirow{3}{*}{board3} & qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} \hline \Xcline{2-5}{1.5pt}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table_caption}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal, but compilable code, not just a screenshot?

Comment: Which package defines the macro `\Xcline`?

Comment: @Mico: It is `makecell`.

Comment: @Bernard: i added code to post

Comment: There are (at least) two ways to highlight the contents of cells -- to use a **bold** font face for the contents, and to cast the entire cell in a color or shade of gray. Which method of emphasis are you trying to implement?

Comment: @Mico: the method proposed by Bernard is ok

Comment: Related: [Coloring a sub-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462753/134144) and [Table with vertical lines that are thick for some rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496638/134144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this solution, which relies on the `boldline` package (`shipunov` bundle), which defines lines of variable thickness for tables, both horizontal and vertical. It uses as an argument a number which represents the multiple of  default line thickness. In the following code, I used  `5`, which means a thickness of `2pt`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl, makecell, caption, multirow}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\diagbox{board}{tag} & tag1 & tag2 & tag3 & tag4 \\ \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{board1} & qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{board2} & qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} &
 qr & dm & ar & ap \\ \cline{2-5} \hline\clineB{2-5}{5}
\multirow{3}{*}{board3}& \multicolumn{1}{V{5}c|}{qr} & dm & ar & \multicolumn{1}{|cV{5}}{ap} \\ \cline{2-5}
 &\multicolumn{1}{V{5}c|}{qr} & dm & ar & \multicolumn{1}{|cV{5}}{ap} \\ \cline{2-5}
 &\multicolumn{1}{V{5}c|}{qr} & dm & ar & \multicolumn{1}{|cV{5}}{ap} \\[2pt] %
\hline
\noalign{\vskip-2.4pt}\clineB{2-5}{5}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block`. You can ``draw'' around the block with the key `draw`.
- The key `hvlines` draws all the rules excepted in the blocks (but if the key `transparent` is used for the blocks, the rules are drawn).
- `{NiceTabular}` has a built-in command `\diagbox` (however, that command doesn't set the size of the cell and that's why I have put a `\rule`).

However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{1.3cm}cccc}[hvlines]
\rule[-8pt]{0pt}{20pt}
\diagbox{board}{tag} & tag1 & tag2 & tag3 &  tag4 \\ 
\Block{3-1}{board1} & qr & dm & ar & ap \\  
&  qr  & dm & ar & ap \\  
&  qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ 
\Block{3-1}{board2} & qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
\Block{3-1}{board3} & 
\Block[transparent,draw,line-width=2pt]{3-4}{} qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you want the bold line within the block, it's also possible but it's a little more complicated (and you have to load Tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wc{1.3cm}cccc}[hvlines]
\rule[-8pt]{0pt}{20pt}
\diagbox{board}{tag} & tag1 & tag2 & tag3 &  tag4 \\ 
\Block{3-1}{board1} & qr & dm & ar & ap \\  
&  qr  & dm & ar & ap \\  
&  qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ 
\Block{3-1}{board2} & qr  & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
\Block{3-1}{board3} & 
\Block[transparent,tikz={clip},tikz={draw,line width=2pt}]{3-4}{} qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap \\ 
& qr & dm & ar & ap 
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]