# Lines between array cells

Tags: arrays, cell, nicematrix, tabularray

I'm looking for a natural way to selectively add horizontal and vertical lines between the cells of an array.

Here is an example.

```
 +-----------+
 | A   B   C | D   E
 |           +-------+
 | F   G   H | I   J |
 +-----------+       |
  K   L   M  | N   O |
             |       |
  P   Q   R  | S   T |
             +-------+
```

I know that I could use multicolumn and multirow commands to achieve that, but it is neither efficient nor elegant, and the resulting code looks horrible.

As every reasonably modern WYSIWYG word processor has an intuitive way to add such lines, I'm sure there is a comparably comfortable method in LaTeX. I just don't know it yet.

Comment: Look at the package `nicematrix`.

Comment: Do you need the *dashed* lines (with different dash sizes)?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462753/134144 may be interesting.

Comment: @projetmbc thank you for the pointer to nicematrix. That looks pretty powerful.

Comment: @Bernard it is not about *dashed* lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `nicematrix` package combines very well with tikz.

Notice that the original data : A, B, etc. are "untouched"

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[cell-space-limits=5pt] % expand the cells
        A&B&C&D&E\\
        F&G&H&I&J\\
        K&L&M&N&O\\
        P&Q&R&S&T
\CodeAfter 
\tikz \draw [dotted] (1-|1) -- (1-|4); 
\tikz \draw [dotted] (3-|1) -- (3-|4); 
\tikz \draw [dashed] (2-|4) -- (2-|6); 
\tikz \draw [dashed] (5-|4) -- (5-|6); 
\tikz \draw  (1-|1) -- (3-|1); 
\tikz \draw  (1-|4) -- (6-|4); 
\tikz \draw  (2-|6) -- (5-|6); 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

**Alternative**

With the `tabularray` package, the style of the table is **totally**  separated from the  content. ([tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray))

Also adds extra space above and below the table rows to make the table look better.

[image: D]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tblr}{% style definition
    vline{1} = {1-2}{solid},        
    vline{4} = {1-5}{solid},
    vline{6} = {2-5}{solid},
    hline{1} = {1-3}{dotted},
    hline{3} = {1-3}{dotted},
    hline{2} = {4-6}{dashed},
    hline{5} = {4-6}{dashed},
}
        A&B&C&D&E\\
        F&G&H&I&J\\
        K&L&M&N&O\\
        P&Q&R&S&T\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It may be simpler to write `hline{1,3} = {1-3}{dotted}` and `hline{2,5} = {4-6}{dashed}`.

Comment: This is an artificial example. For the actual work, I found the independence between content and style to be more relevant. In my workflow, I do calculations, queries, and sorting  outside of LaTeX and then import the data for publishing only. It is not unusual for the data to change between  drafts and the final version.

Answer (score 7):

How about the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ccc|cc}
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{A} & B & C & D & E                      \\ \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{F} & G & H & I & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{J} \\ \cline{1-3}
K                      & L & M & N & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{O} \\
P                      & Q & R & S & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{T} \\ \cline{4-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is generated from https://www.tablesgenerator.com

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know tablesgenerator.com. The resulting code is better than what I thought when I wrote "I know that I could use multicolumn and multirow commands to achieve that but it is neither efficient nor elegant, and the resulting code looks horrible.". But still...

Comment: @azimut, you are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Use `hhline` and some abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcommand{\RR}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}}
\newcommand{\LR}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hhline{|---|~~}
\LR{A} & B & \RR{C} & D & E \\
\hhline{|~~~|--|}
\LR{F} & G & \RR{H} & I & \RR{J} \\
\hhline{|---|~~|}
K      & L & \RR{M} & N & \RR{O} \\
P      & Q & \RR{R} & S & \RR{T} \\
\hhline{~~~|--|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

In the argument to `\hhline` a hyphen means “rule in this column”, a tilde means “no rule”. With `|` one specifies a “meeting” of rules.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `nicematrix` have been given by Simon Dispa. Here is another solution with `nicematrix`. It uses the command `\Block`. That command has been designed to merge cells (horizontally and vertically) and put contents at the center of the resulting rectangle. However, it's possible to use it without content in order to use only the key `draw`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[cell-space-limits=5pt]
\Block[draw]{2-3}{}
A & B & C & D & E \\
F & G & H & \Block[draw]{3-2}{}
            I & J \\
K & L & M & N & O \\
P & Q & R & S & T
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]